# PHP - How to parse XML with arabic character

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

I am facing to a parsing problem in PHP. Indeed, when I parse google suggest result in french, the url I am trying to parse is :

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=toolbar&hl=fr&q=exemple

I parse it with the following code:

```
$file = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=toolbar&hl=fr&q=exemple';
$xml =simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode(file_get_contents(urldecode($file ))));
print_r($xml);
```

And the results are oK.

When I do it in arabic, I replace lang and query. the code is following

```
$file = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=toolbar&hl=ar&q=من هو';
$xml =simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode(file_get_contents(urldecode($file ))));
print_r($xml);
```

The url is OK but I get a warning when I parse it

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents([http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=toolbar&hl=ar&q=من](http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=toolbar&hl=ar&q=%D9%85%D9%86)
>   هو): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad
>   Request

This problem has been solved thank to shukshin.ivan but I'm facing now to a displaying problem. The print_r return as following

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [CompleteSuggestion] => Array ( [0] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ ÇÑØÛÑá ) ) ) [1] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ ØÇÑÞ ÑãÖÇä ) ) ) [2] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ ãÍãæÏ ÇáÍÓäÇÊ ) ) ) [3] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ ÈÇÈÇ äæíá ) ) ) [4] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ ãÄÓÓ ÌæÌá ) ) ) [5] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ åãÇã ÍæÊ ) ) ) [6] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ Ðæ ÇáÞÑäíä ) ) ) [7] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ ÇÈæ Úáí ÇáÍÇßã ) ) ) [8] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ ÚãÑæ Èä ÚËãÇä ) ) ) [9] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [suggestion] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [data] => ãä åæ ÇÈæ ãÑÉ ) ) ) ) )

Is it encoding that is wrong? Meta charset of the page is utf8.
When I do the same thing with the hardcoded xml file, everything is ok.
Am I missing anything else?

If you are russian, I have the same problem with cyrillic character

```
$file = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=toolbar&hl=ru&q=' . urlencode('Я');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't `urldecode` the whole url. You should `urlencode` (encode, not decode) the string. The following code works fine.

```
$file = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=toolbar&hl=ar&q=' . urlencode('من هو');
$xml =simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode(file_get_contents($file )));
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is that character displayed by the print_r are wrong... Which encoding do I have to use to display it on a page?

Comment: Well, I've helped with the problem set: `http 400` error.

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: Do you think it could be my browser?

Comment: Well, kind of encoding issue, I see correct russian suggestions in my browser. Anyway, you'd better split the problem into two tasks. The first one (http problem) is solved and my answer should be accepted as right. The second problem(encoding) should be investigated in different question and need some debugging work.